# Is lift for Association Rules the same in both direction?

Tags: interpretation, association-rules

I am just discovering Association Rules, but am a little confused, particularly with the interpretation of the results. My main question is - is the Lift for two items always the same in both directions? Meaning does **Lift(B → A)** always equal **Lift(A → B)**?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question would be straightforward from looking at the formula.

$$
\operatorname{lift}(X \to Y) = \frac{\operatorname{P}(X \cap Y)}{\operatorname{P}(X)\operatorname{P}(Y)}
$$

The expression is symmetric with respect to $X$ and $Y$.

It is the exponentiation of the pointwise mutual information: a value of 1 indicates no more association than chance.

More information is available [from Michael Hahsler](https://michael.hahsler.net/research/association_rules/measures.html#lift), who maintains the `arules` package.